# How to clear files obtained by curl

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, curl

I am working on Debian Stable Linux (regularly updated). I installed nodejs from repository but did not get `node` and `npm` commands. Hence, I tried using instructions from this page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-compile/tutorial :

I ran this command:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo -E bash -
```

and though I got a 'deprecated' message, I allowed it to run. Then I ran:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

However, `node` and `js` commands were still not available. I then installed `nodejs-dev` but still no luck. As given on above link, `node -v` and `npm -v` still do not work.

I hence removed (purged) nodejs and nodejs-dev packages. I have 2 questions:

1. Are there any changed made by curl command above that I need to reverse?
2. How to get `node` and `npm` commands?

Thanks for your help.

### Edit:

Following is the output of commands used for installation:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo -E bash -

================================================================================
================================================================================

                           SCRIPT DEPRECATION WARNING                         

  This script, located at https://deb.nodesource.com/setup, used to
  install Node.js v0.10, is being deprecated and will eventually be made
  inactive.

  You should use the script that corresponds to the version of Node.js you
  wish to install. e.g.

   * https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x — Node.js v4 LTS "Argon" (recommended)
   * https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x — Node.js v6 Current

  Please see https://github.com/nodejs/LTS/ for details about which version
  may be appropriate for you.

  The NodeSource Node.js Linux distributions GitHub repository contains
  information about which versions of Node.js and which Linux distributions
  are supported and how to use the install scripts.
    https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

================================================================================
================================================================================

Continuing in 10 seconds (press Ctrl-C to abort) ...


## Installing the NodeSource Node.js v0.10 repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Ign:1 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch InRelease
Get:2 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Hit:3 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch InRelease                                                               
Hit:4 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch Release                                                                            
Get:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [62.9 kB]                                               
Get:6 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages.diff/Index [1,720 B]
Hit:7 http://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/d-apt d-apt InRelease                                                  
Get:8 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-updates/main Translation-en.diff/Index [1,720 B]
Get:9 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Contents (deb).diff/Index [2,212 B]
Get:11 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages 2017-10-26-2029.42.pdiff [871 B]
Get:12 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-updates/main Translation-en 2017-10-26-2029.42.pdiff [544 B]
Get:11 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages 2017-10-26-2029.42.pdiff [871 B]
Get:12 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-updates/main Translation-en 2017-10-26-2029.42.pdiff [544 B]
Get:13 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Contents (deb) 2017-10-26-2029.42.pdiff [15.9 kB]
Get:13 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Contents (deb) 2017-10-26-2029.42.pdiff [15.9 kB]
Get:14 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 Packages [186 kB]
Get:15 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main Translation-en [86.2 kB]
Fetched 449 kB in 3s (144 kB/s)         
Reading package lists... Done

## Installing packages required for setup: apt-transport-https...

+ apt-get install -y apt-transport-https > /dev/null 2>&1

## You seem to be using Debian version stretch.
## This maps to Debian "jessie"... Adjusting for you...

## Confirming "jessie" is supported...

+ curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.10/dists/jessie/Release'

## Adding the NodeSource signing key to your keyring...

+ curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
OK

## Creating apt sources list file for the NodeSource Node.js v0.10 repo...

+ echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.10 jessie main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
+ echo 'deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.10 jessie main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

## Running `apt-get update` for you...

+ apt-get update
Ign:1 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch InRelease                                                               
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease                                                             
Hit:4 http://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/d-apt d-apt InRelease                           
Get:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.10 jessie InRelease [3,899 B]    
Hit:6 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://debianmirror.nkn.in/debian stretch Release
Get:9 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.10 jessie/main Sources [687 B]
Get:10 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.10 jessie/main i386 Packages [928 B]
Fetched 5,514 B in 2s (2,686 B/s)  
Reading package lists... Done

================================================================================
================================================================================

                       NODE.JS v0.10 DEPRECATION WARNING                      

  Node.js v0.10 will cease to be actively supported in October 2016.

  This means you will not continue to receive security or critical stability
  updates for this version of Node.js beyond that time.

  You should begin migration to a newer version of Node.js as soon as
  possible. Use the installation script that corresponds to the version of
  Node.js you wish to install. e.g.

   * https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x — Node.js v4 LTS "Argon" (recommended)
   * https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x — Node.js v6 Current

  Please see https://github.com/nodejs/LTS/ for details about which version
  may be appropriate for you.

  The NodeSource Node.js Linux distributions GitHub repository contains
  information about which versions of Node.js and which Linux distributions
  are supported and how to use the install scripts.
    https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

================================================================================
================================================================================

Continuing in 5 seconds ...


## Run `apt-get install nodejs` (as root) to install Node.js v0.10 and npm

$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libuv1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libuv1 nodejs
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,512 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Selecting previously unselected package libuv1:i386.
(Reading database ... 255826 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libuv1_1.9.1-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libuv1:i386 (1.9.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_4.8.2~dfsg-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (4.8.2~dfsg-1) ...
Setting up libuv1:i386 (1.9.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up nodejs (4.8.2~dfsg-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/nodejs to provide /usr/bin/js (js) in auto mode

$
```

Comment: I believe this question belongs to SuperUser instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: agreed, ServerFault or SuperUser, i'm not sure which, but not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo -E bash -`

It downloads a bash script and directly executes with sudo permission. This can be very dangerous. Don't do it.

Instead `curl -O https://deb.nodesource.com/setup`
Just check the script by `less setup`. If it looks fine, execute by `sudo setup`

**Answer for your first question.**

setup is a package installer script. It adds some packages to sources.list and installs some gpg keys. It's not necessary to reverse the changes made by it.

Comment: I have added output of installation commands in my question above. I think I can remove nodesource.list from /etc/apt/sources.list.d folder. The file contains: `deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.10 jessie main ; deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.10 jessie main`
`